# Visual Studio Code всплывающие подсказки

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Можно ли сделать всплывающие подсказки на русском языке?**

(Речь именно о всплывающих подсказках при наведении курсора на тег или атрибут, как на скриншоте.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно. А вам это зачем? Вы хотите сделать что-то своё или у вас затруднения с английским? Если последнее, то лучше учите язык - будете понимать не только подсказки.

Comment: Здравствуйте, да, у меня есть затруднения с английским. Я знаю, лучше когда интерфейс vscode на английском и все остальное тоже, и я наверное так и сделаю по вашем совету спасибо, но в будущем,

Comment: А пока я только начинаю погружаться в мир Frontend-разработки, и чувствую что лучше пока на русском сделать vscode, с интерфейсом получилось а вот с подсказками не знаю как, если вы знаете буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Я не знаю наверняка, но это зависит от расширения, которые вы установили. Поищите, есть вероятность того, что сможете найти какой-то русскоязычный пакет.

Comment: Я не нашел такие расширения, которые бы именно подсказки на русский переводили.